# Как ищется адрес в сети?

Tags: linux, сеть

Книги есть по сетям, но я не знаю где найти нужную информацию, а читать от корки до корки долго. Делаю игру. Мне нужно реализовать сеть. Я как то читал таненбаума, но плохо помню. В общем думаю что реальный пример как ищется ip в сети, подойдёт в игре. Сам логически не могу придумать. Например если адрес находится в одной сети, а другой адрес находится через четыре, пять маршрутизаторов. Как мне найти этот хост. Мне надо это сделать, чтобы реализовать команду ping и traceroute, ну и чтобы можно было подключаться по сети к подлюченногому компьютеру в сети. И вот вопрос, как роутер ищет компьютер в сети, он же не на все порты отсылвает запрос наверное?

Comment: Если компьютеры в разных подсетях то единственный способ узнать адрес другой машины, явно спросить его у машины, адрес которой известен. Т.е. вам нужен некий сервер на который обращаются все игровые клиенты и сообщают свои адреса (вернее достаточно просто послать некий запрос "я тут", а сервер сам увидит от кого пришел пакет). Сервер соответственно запоминает все эти адреса и высылает их другим клиентам по необходимости

Comment: [маршрутизация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: А роутер вообще ничего не ищет. получив ip пакет он пытается его отправить в тот сегмент, куда указывает таблица маршрутизации. Если при этом адрес канального уровня точки назначения не известен - то используется протокол определеия адреса канального уровня (для ethernet сетей и ip это запрос по протоколу arp)

Comment: И конечно не забывайте, что 90% людей находятся за NAT и таким образом до них вообще нельзя достучаться зная ip адрес и не применяя техник STUN. И даже в случае использования STUN около 50% пробить не удается и требуется пересылка всего трафика через сервер

Comment: @Mike я делаю не сетевую игру а симуляцию сети.

Comment: @xverizex Если вы делаете симуляцию сети то вам все равно придется прочитать довольно много литературы по всем уровням OSI. И глубоко изучить вопросы маршрутизации (а возможно и преобразования адресов канального уровня). Потому что краткий ответ: "маршрутизаторы используют таблицу маршрутизации для поиска клиентов", а чуть более полный ответ - сотня страниц текста

Comment: @Mike но я как помню что роутер содержит у себя в таблице только ближайший адрес. Как он знает что на этот адрес слать данные? Или роутеры запоминают пакет, этот пакет по всем роутерам пробежится и когда ответ будет получен, то он найдёт дорогу назад.

Comment: @xverizex Роутер содержит у себя адреса всех подсетей с которыми хочет общаться. Если адреса в таблице нет, то пакет будет выброшен. Другое дело, что подсеть может быть разной ширины, в том числе и охватывающей все возможные адреса (маршрут по умолчанию). И в большинстве случаев простые роутеры содержат адреса только сетей к которым подключены и этот самый маршрут по умолчанию, куда отправляют все пакеты, которым не нашлось других маршрутов. И "дорога назад" для пакета может быть вообще не такой, как была дорога вперед, все решают только существующие таблицы.

Comment: @Mike, а перенесите этот свой коммент в ответ. Добавьте для полноты ссылки на RIP, EIGRP и OSPF и пару слов о TTL

Answer (score 1):

Роутер понимает, куда дальше отправить пакет, очень просто: из пакета берётся destination address и на него по очереди накладывается маска подсети из каждой записи таблицы маршрутизации роутера. После наложения маски результат сравнивается с адресом подсети из этой записи. Если совпало — пакет отправляется на адрес, указанный в качестве шлюза для этой подсети. Default gateway имеет адреc подсети и маску подсети 0.0.0.0, поэтому, если до него дошла проверка, он совпадает всегда (в случае, если имеется, конечно).

А вообще, читайте Олиферов. От корки до корки, иначе информация в голове будет фрагментарной, да вы ещё и не будете знать, каких фрагментов не хватает.

Comment: Спасибо. Уже читаю.

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, разделите у себя в голове уровни пакетов, транспорта и приложений. Не надо передавать пакеты от клиента к клиенту. Вас прежде всего интересует *связь между клиентами* - то есть вам нужен транспорт *данных* (не пакетов) между ними.

Про пакеты знать не обязательно. Достаточно знать, как организовать транспорт данных от клиента к серверу (потому что сервер видят все - например по домену server.ru, а клиенты друг друга - в большинстве случаев не увидят никогда). Самый простой транспорт - это TCP-соединение, клиент-сервер, внутри которого можно передавать данные в любом формате. Есть еще множество протоколов - FTP, HTTP, SOAP  - и они все используют TCP для транспортировки своих *данных* по сети.

Если у вас сетевое приложение, и пользователи должны будут связываться друг с другом далее чем в локальной сети и обмениваться данными - нужна серверная часть. Один пользователь соединиться с сервером, передаст данные для другого пользователя, другой соединиться и получит эти данные. Как именно соединяются пользователи с сервером - не важно. И какие пакеты там ходят, по каким кабелям или WiFi - тем более не важно.

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли. Я делаю не сетевую игру. В самой игре симуляция сети происходит. Нужно понять как роутеры знают куда передать дальше пакет.

Comment: Тем не менее во многих играх для сокращения сетевых задержек клиенты общаются напрямую во всех случаях, когда это возможно. Так что фразы "_Не надо передавать пакеты от клиента к клиенту_" быть не должно. Разработчик сам решает как ему нужно передавать.

Comment: @xverizex Роутеры хранят таблицу маршрутизации, в которой явно указано для каких адресов куда отправлять пакеты

Comment: @xverizex, **"Нужно понять как роутеры знают куда передать дальше пакет."** - маршрутизаторы на основе разных алгоритмов строит у себя топологию сети. Из неё они и узнают, куда что отправлять. Почитайте [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/111558/). А если хотите более конкретно понять как это всё работает, пройдите курсы CISCO в их интернет академии.

Comment: @MiMEKiZ вот ещё вопрос. Что получается, что в интернете у одного роутера вся таблица маршрутизации заполнена, даже например если маршрутизатор стоит в России, он знает о маршрутах тех, что знает роутер в Японии?

Comment: @xverizex, каждый роутер не знает о 100% всех других роутеров. Он знает ближайшее окружение. Как далеко он заглядывает зависит так же и от алгоритма. Теперь у вас будет вопрос, а почему бы им не строить на максимальную удаленность? А очень просто. В алгоритмах заложено, что раз в N секунд будет переопрос своего окружения, и если кто-то стал не доступен, то он вынужден переделывать топологию по новой, уже без отвалившегося звена. А на опрос и построение уходят драгоценное время. Чтобы свести возможно потери к минимуму, избрали путь опроса ближайщих соседей.

Comment: @xverizex, под потерями имеется ввиду то, что если маршрутизатор Г упал, а у маршрутизатора А в таблице построен короткий путь к Д через Г. То А еще не знает, что пути через Г нет. И он будет гнать пакеты в пустоту. И прекратит он это делать, когда перестроит маршрут. (Это всё вкратце и по сельски. В самом деле ситуация чуть более сложнее, чем описано мной)

Comment: @xverizex, добавлю то, как идет опрос соседних роутеров. Каждый роутер делает запрос на ближайший, и запрашивает информацию у них о том, какие они знают сети. И на основе такой информации, они синхронизируют свои таблицы\базы маршрутов.

Comment: @MiMEKiZ, ну админы довольно часто грузят полную таблицу BGP, так что не соглашусь с вашим утверждением. Другое дело — маршрутизация ipv6.